# How to use chdir() in Maxima in a more flexible way?

Tags: maxima, chdir

I often put the following lines at the beginning of my Maxima files

```
load("operatingsystem")$ 
chdir("/Users/tilda/Documents/progs/maxima/spm/")$
```

to make sure that output created by other programs from within Maxima is written into the current working directory as indicated above.

It does its job, yet this method is rather **inflexible** as the user's home directory, i.e.

> /Users/tilda

is hardcoded into the program. So, when I exchange these files, users have to manually edit and adjust the code to their $HOME. To fix this I changed the code to various forms of

```
load("operatingsystem")$ 
chdir("$HOME/Documents/progs/maxima/spm/")$
```

just to get (Lisp) error messages. After consulting the manual and some trial and error I came up with this:

```
(%i1) load("operatingsystem")$
      getenv("HOME")$
      chdir(%)$
      chdir("Documents/progs/maxima/spm/")$
      getcurrentdirectory();
```

which works fine. For other users, i.e. *matthias*, the current directory now indeed is in their path.

```
(%o5) /Users/matthias/Documents/progs/maxima/spm/
```

However, I wonder if there is a more **elegant** and shorter **way** to achieve this.

Any suggestions appreciated.

Cheers
Tilda

Comment: Looks like you have a working solution. I don't know if there is anything more elegant. Something to consider, you could add the path in question to `file_search_maxima` and/or `file_search_lisp` and omit the calls to `chdir`.

Comment: @RobertDodier Thanks for your fast reply and the suggestion to try `file_search_maxima` or `file_search_lisp` instead. But aren't these functions used for maxima- or lisp-files to be read in or written to disk? Where as my intention is to write, say output crated by **draw2d**, to a specified directory. So, I guess I'll have to stick to `chdir`.